# find a subset using lapply/apply in a data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have two data frames *cell* and *support* (shown below). I want a subset of 'cell' using the following condition: all the rows of 'support' that match with vector ***b*** element-wise. my output will consist of all those rows of 'cell'.

```
a<-c(0,1,0)
b<-c(0,0,1)
level = c(3,2,4)
zero = c(1,2,1)


cell <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(level, seq))    #create all cell
support <- t(apply(cell, 1, function(x) +(x != zero)))


> cell
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    1    1
2     2    1    1
3     3    1    1
4     1    2    1
5     2    2    1
6     3    2    1
7     1    1    2
8     2    1    2
9     3    1    2
10    1    2    2
11    2    2    2
12    3    2    2
13    1    1    3
14    2    1    3
15    3    1    3
16    1    2    3
17    2    2    3
18    3    2    3
19    1    1    4
20    2    1    4
21    3    1    4
22    1    2    4
23    2    2    4
24    3    2    4
> support
      Var1 Var2 Var3
 [1,]    0    1    0
 [2,]    1    1    0
 [3,]    1    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    0
 [5,]    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    0
 [7,]    0    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1
[10,]    0    0    1
[11,]    1    0    1
[12,]    1    0    1
[13,]    0    1    1
[14,]    1    1    1
[15,]    1    1    1
[16,]    0    0    1
[17,]    1    0    1
[18,]    1    0    1
[19,]    0    1    1
[20,]    1    1    1
[21,]    1    1    1
[22,]    0    0    1
[23,]    1    0    1
[24,]    1    0    1
> hD<-lapply(1:nrow(cell), function (x) cell[which(sum(support[x,]==b)==3),])
> do.call(rbind, hD)
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    1    1
2    1    1    1
3    1    1    1
```

I tried to use lapply but I am not getting the expected output. My output should be row 10,16, and 22 of the ***cell*** (shown below) as rows 10,16, and 22 of support match exactly with vector ***b***. I do not want to use any loop.

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    2    2
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare `b` values to each row in `support` by transposing it and select the rows in `cell` where all values match.

```
cell[colSums(t(support) == b) == length(b), ]

#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#10    1    2    2
#16    1    2    3
#22    1    2    4
```

This can also be done using `sweep` :

```
cell[rowSums(sweep(support, 2, b, `==`)) == length(b), ]
```

---

To compare with both `a` and `b` we can match them individually :

```
cell[colSums(t(support) == b) == length(b) | 
     colSums(t(support) == a) == length(a), ]
```

Or use `lapply` :

```
cell[Reduce(`|`, lapply(list(a, b), function(x) 
           colSums(t(support) == x) == length(x))), ]
```

Comment: if I add one more condition: all the rows that matches with vector a and b. a matches with row 1. how will you add this condition in code?

Comment: @Dihan you can combine the two conditions `cell[colSums(t(support) == b) == length(b) | colSums(t(support) == a) == length(a), ]`. See updated answer.

Comment: ```yz<-1

level = 3
zero = 2


> H_D(level,zero,yz)
Error in colSums(support == x) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```
  Can you fix this error? This happens when I use colSums.

Comment: @Dihan Shouldn't the length of `level` and `zero` be same as `a` and `b`? How will you compare both of them then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option

```
subset(cell,Reduce(`&`,as.data.frame(t(t(support)==b))))
```

or

```
subset(cell,Reduce(`&`,as.data.frame(support == t(replicate(nrow(support),b)))))
```

which gives

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
10    1    2    2
16    1    2    3
22    1    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an `apply` logic, which is applicable to both requirements.

```
cell[apply(support, 1, function(x) all(x == b)), ]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 10    1    2    2
# 16    1    2    3
# 22    1    2    4

cell[apply(support, 1, function(x) all(x == b) | all(x == a)), ]
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1     1    1    1
# 10    1    2    2
# 16    1    2    3
# 22    1    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
cell[!rowSums(support != b[col(support)]),]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#10    1    2    2
#16    1    2    3
#22    1    2    4
```

Comment: ```yz<-1

level = 3
zero = 2


> H_D(level,zero,yz)
Error in colSums(support == x) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```
  Can you fix this error? This happens when I use colSums.

Comment: @Dihan The error seems to be related to the object structure.  Do you have a `vector` or `data.frame/matrix`.  In the example, I find `cell` to be `data.frame`. If it is a `vector`, then you could get such an error. i.e. `v1 <- 1:5; colSums(v1)#Error in colSums(v1) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`

Comment: It could be a vector or data frame. It works fine for data frame. I tried drop=FALSE but not working!

Comment: @Dihan As I said, if it is a `vector`, it won't work with `rowSums` or `colSums`.  You can create a check with `if(is.vector(cell))) do this else do that`